# Apache virtualhosts conf let wrong servername requests going through proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, django, mod-proxy, port-scanning

I have moved a server configuration to a new server and at the same time configured it with apache mod_proxy to access a gunicorn/django webserver (inside a docker container on port 8000). Previous server was using apache mod_wsgi to access django directly.

**So I changed some virtualhosts configuration but I do not understand why now some requests are going through apache to django, when the request servername is not one of my DNS and virtualhosts configurations...**

For now, django stops them with `Invalid HTTP_HOST header` errors, but I would like to filter them in apache configuration directly, and to understand how such scanning requests might pass DNS and apache configurations.

Here is what looks like a typical django error I received:

```
Report at /
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'sprucetips.cyou'. You may need to add 'sprucetips.cyou' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://sprucetips.cyou/
Django Version: 2.2.28
Python Executable: /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 3.5.10
...

Request information:
USER: [unable to retrieve the current user]
GET: No GET data
POST: No POST data
FILES: No FILES data
COOKIES: No cookie data

META:
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = 'gzip'
HTTP_CONNECTION = 'Keep-Alive'
HTTP_HOST = 'sprucetips.cyou'
HTTP_USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR = '34.220.181.252'
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST = 'sprucetips.cyou'
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO = 'https'
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER = 'mydomain.ca'
PATH_INFO = '/'
QUERY_STRING = ''
RAW_URI = '/'
REMOTE_ADDR = '172.23.0.1'
REMOTE_PORT = '47332'
REQUEST_METHOD = 'GET'
SCRIPT_NAME = ''
SERVER_NAME = '0.0.0.0'
SERVER_PORT = '8000'
SERVER_PROTOCOL = 'HTTP/1.1'
SERVER_SOFTWARE = 'gunicorn/20.1.0'
...
```

My DNS is configured on two domain names, mydomain.ca and mydomain.com. I previously set a DNS config for each subdomain but now I only set `mydomain.ca` `*.mydomain.ca` `mydomain.com` `*.mydomain.com` all to the same IP. Can this be a problem?

And there are my virtualhosts:

First `001-mydomain.ca.conf` to redirect any 80 port request to 443 port

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain.ca
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.com www.mydomain.ca mydomain.com sub1.mydomain.ca sub2.mydomain.ca sub3.mydomain.ca

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mydomain.ca.error.log
        LogLevel info
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mydomain.ca.access.log combined

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mydomain.ca [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.com [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mydomain.com [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.ca
        RewriteRule ^ https://mydomain.ca%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]

        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =sub1.mydomain.ca
        RewriteRule ^ https://sub1.mydomain.ca%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]

        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =sub2.mydomain.ca
        RewriteRule ^ https://sub2.mydomain.ca%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]

        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =sub3.mydomain.ca
        RewriteRule ^ https://sub3.mydomain.ca%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

`010-mydomain.ca-ssl.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName mydomain.ca
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.ca sub1.mydomain.ca sub2.mydomain.ca
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.ca

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mydomain.ca.error.log
        LogLevel debug

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mydomain.ca.access.log combined

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.ca/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.ca/privkey.pem

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteMap exceptions /var/www/mydomain.ca/maintenance_exceptions.map

        RewriteCond /var/www/mydomain.ca/maintenance.html -f
        RewriteCond /var/www/mydomain.ca/maintenance.enable -f
        RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
        RewriteCond ${exceptions:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} !OK
        RewriteRule ^.*$ /maintenance.html [R=503,L]
        ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO 'https' env=HTTPS
        ProxyPass /static/ !
        ProxyPass /media/ !
        ProxyPass /favicon.ico !
        ProxyPass /maintenance.html !
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/

        Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/mydomain.ca/favicon.ico
        Alias /media/ /var/www/mydomain.ca/media/
        Alias /static/ /var/www/mydomain.ca/static/

        <Directory /var/www/mydomain.ca>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/mydomain.ca/static>
                Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, must-revalidate"
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^ https://mydomain.ca%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

One of the subdomains is redirected to another webserver with `011-sub3.mydomain.ca-ssl.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName sub3.mydomain.ca

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sub3.mydomain.ca.error.log
        LogLevel debug
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sub3.mydomain.ca.access.log combined

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.ca/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.ca/privkey.pem

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests off
        AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
        ProxyPass /.well-know !
        ProxyPass /robots.txt !
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/ nocanon
</VirtualHost>
```

And I finally manage others subdomains and direct IPrequests in `020-default.mydomain.ca.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
        ServerName default.mydomain.ca
        ServerAlias *.mydomain.ca *.mydomain.com
        Redirect 404 /
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mydomain.ca.other.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
        ServerName <IP>
        Redirect 403 /
        ErrorDocument 403 "Direct IP access not allowed"
        UseCanonicalName Off
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mydomain.ca.other.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any tip, advise or magic answer would be so appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to AlexD's [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1137354/274176) that the default VirtualHost should be the first one, `<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>` would not work, because `*:80` is for plain HTTP and `*:443` for HTTPS. You need to separate these configurations and add the TLS settings including any certificate for the `<VirtualHost *:443>`.

---

Furthermore, the `RewriteRule`s in your HTTP to HTTPS redirection are a bit overly complicated.

For the subdomains you could use [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) with a single rule with variables:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub1.example.net
    ServerAlias sub2.example.net sub3.example.net

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

For the hostnames that should be redirected to the canonical hostname, [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) would be [preferable](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.net
    ServerAlias www.example.com www.example.net example.com 

    Redirect "/" "https://www.example.net/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: As I respond to @AlexD, modifying the order of my virtualhosts cause SSL errors.
Splitting 443 and 80 directives is working well, as your suggestions for rewriting to HTTPS. Thanks.
Still having Invalid HTTPS_HOST header errors, and I do not understand how such requests pass the proxy...

Comment: Ok, I forgot to "add the TLS settings", now it is working well. I hope the port scanning requests will now be blocked by apache config.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Not totally, with the wildcard virtualhost set as default virtualhost, sub1/sub2/sub3.mydomain.ca are not available then. For now I split the default virtualhost: direct IP as default virtual host, and wildcards as last virtualhost as defined first. I will check if port-scanning requests still pass through or not: is it the virtualhost with direct IP that is suppose to stop them?

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost)

> When a request is received, the server first maps it to the best matching  based on the local IP address and port combination only. Non-wildcards have a higher precedence. If no match based on IP and port occurs at all, the "main" server configuration is used.

> If multiple virtual hosts contain the best matching IP address and port, the server selects from these virtual hosts the best match based on the requested hostname. If no matching name-based virtual host is found, then the first listed virtual host that matched the IP address will be used. As a consequence, **the first listed virtual host for a given IP address and port combination is the default virtual host for that IP and port combination**.

You need to rename your `020-default.mydomain.ca.conf` to `000-default.mydomain.ca.conf` so it goes the first.

Comment: I do not understand why, but moving these hosts as default virtual hosts like you suggest cause a SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG error (firefox) or ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR error (chrome)
I tried with the same file and also with the suggestion of @esa-jokinen to separate 80 port virtualhost and 443 port virtualhost, but still an error.
Also I was aware of this apache documentation. I was thinking mydomain.ca is my default virtual host, and the default.mydomain.ca is just here to manage any other subdomain or the cases when users use the IP directly.